# Enabling bwn in FreeBSD

Tags: networking, freebsd, wifi, broadcom

I am trying to load the bwn driver as a module as mentioned in [the man page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bwn&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

However, when I attempted to edit `/boot/defaults/loader.conf` I could not write the changes to the file, this was attempted as root.

Then I read that this file is not to be edited. How can I load this driver as a module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `if_bwn_load="yes"` in `/boot/loader.conf`. If you don't have a `/boot/loader.conf` file on your system, just create it. As with the `/etc/defaults/rc.conf` file, `/boot/defaults/loader.conf` contains default values that can be overridden in a per-system fashion.

Of course, you'll need to either reboot the system to pick up the new setting, or load the module manually the first time with `kldload if_bwn`.